# How to specific pass fields in custom rest api for get product Information

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm creating custom **rest API** for getting a **list of products**.
In my module, I have just use the **getList** function of **ProductRepository**.
I need to pass select specific fields in API.
so, how can I get that??

**Note:** In core API, we can get these response using below URL:

> rest/V1/products?fields=items[name,qty,sku],total_count

I want to pass these fields programmatically.

Comment: you can use search Criteria using column name

Comment: can you explain me , how can i achieve that??

Answer (score 1):

> you have an API(rest/V1/products) -you can use search Criteria.

**API(rest/V1/products)**

> you can use **search Criteria** using Column name

```
    http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products/?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={VALUE}&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq
```

> method type : **GET**

**The system creates an array, as shown in the following pseudo-code.**

```
searchCriteria => [
  'filterGroups' => [
    0 => [
      'filters' => [
         0 => [
           'field' => 'name',
           'value' => 'YOUR VALUE',
           'condition_type' => 'eq'
         ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: I know this..but it's used for add where condition in result & i want to pass specific fields in select criteria.

Comment: Please elaborate your concern.